# how to know if grid or list view is active with custom magento page

Tags: list, magento, gridview, grid, toolbar

I have a custom product list page and i´m using the following code to show the pagenumbering and filters:

```
$pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager');
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list_toolbar')->setChild('product_list_toolbar_pager', $pager)->setCollection($products)->toHtml();
```

If i'm changing the mode from grid to list view nothing happens.

How can i get the active mode (grid or list).

Magento normaly uses $this->getMode() but this one doesnt work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fixed it with the following code:

```
$mode = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list_toolbar')->setChild('product_list_toolbar_pager', $pager)->getCurrentMode();
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution,

```
if(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->getDisplayMode())
{
    $productListMode=Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->getDisplayMode();
}
```